# how to trigger a phone call on button click in a php website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My client needed a hyperlink for a click to call feature so i include following line

```
<a href="tel:917387084384">Call +91-7387084384</a>
```

However, requirements have changed from hyperlink to button, so need to know how to include click to call feature with a button

please let me know if you need any clarifications from my side. thanks.

Comment: `<a class="buttonstyleclass" href="tel:917387084384">Call +91-7387084384</a>`

Comment: Last time I checked, you can style hyperlinks to look like buttons. Or anything you need.

Comment: @N.B. and @ MarkBaker : don't assume incompetence, try to understand why. Simple case is when you have a wrap link of a service box which links to more info about the service and INSIDE you have a call-the-service-number link :) *last time I checked, you can't have link inside a link...* :)

Comment: @jave.web - really? You're going to start this because of styling? In 2018? That's *really* what you want to do? I spent more time typing this reply than it would take to style that button. Seriously.. don't, please. Thanks.

Comment: @N.B. No, not because of styling, this question is not about styling at all - it refers to a semantic approach of w3 which says you can't have a link inside a link, if you do and you have a click to call action inside post link, you need to trigger it somehow. yes, you can put it semantically sideways and absolute-style it over, but as you said - it's 2018 :)

Comment: @jave.web did you read the question and Mark's and my comment? The dude wants to style an `a` element to look like button. That's doable. With CSS. This whole semantic bs is something you brought to this question for no reason except - you didn't read. Start reading.

Comment: @N.B. I **did** read. What OP really wanted is one thing, what OP asked is the second one. Now you know, but you didn't before and still instead of thinking of possibilities you've automatically assumed nonsense, that is what I was unhappy about :)

Comment: @jave.web any other things you're unhappy about? Let's fix them all while we're here, I've got this magic shtick here, I just need to wave and imagination becomes reality. I won't even ask you to rub me. I just love fulfilling SJW wishes, that's my life's purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step-by-step guide to turn a hyperlink into button:

1. Rename the `a` tag into `form` and the `href` attribute into `action`:

   `<form action="tel:917387084384">Call +91-7387084384</form>`
2. Wrap the text into a `button` tag:

   `<form action="tel:917387084384"><button>Call +91-7387084384</button></form>`
3. Add the `type` attribute to the `button` tag and set it to `submit`:

   `<form action="tel:917387084384"><button type="submit">Call +91-7387084384</button></form>`

And you're done!

Comment: not wrking if we use this webpage in android webView

Comment: it does not work with an android smartphone & chrome.

Comment: @jerome: Which method does the form use when it is not showing your expected result in android (which version?) and chrome (which version?). Is it "get" or "post"? Please try both and let me know the results.

Comment: I don't have these info -just asked to a friend to test. here is a test page if you need to investigate : http://jmx.alwaysdata.net/sandbox/trigger_phone_call.html Seems the prefered methods are to use <a href="tel:..." or <button onclick="location='tel:...'" (works on any tested UP TO DATE devices so far) older devices may need document.location try a stack search on "window.location document.location"

Answer (score 6):

You could simply style the button to look exactly like a button, or you could use an `onclick` event handler:

```
<button onclick="document.location.href = 'tel:917387084384'">Call +91-7387084384</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will make the browser ask you for permission to launch Skype when clicked:

```
<button onclick="window.location='tel:917387084384';">Hot line</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be called using `document.createElement`

```
function btnClick() {
  const linkElement = document.createElement("a")
  linkElement.href = 'tel:+123456789'
  linkElement.click()
}
```